# Generating interrupts while reading user input in Python

Tags: python

I appreciate all your help. My uncle helped me figure it out. I don't know if it's the best way to do it, but it worked and that's all I needed.

```
import time

name = raw_input("Hi, what is your name?")
print "hi, " + name + ", nice to meet you."
a1 = raw_input("Would you like to hear a knock knock joke?").lower()
if a1 == "no":
    print "OK, thanks anyways"
elif a1 == "yes":
    raw_input ("Knock Knock")
print "interrupting cow"
time.sleep(2)
print "MOOOOOO!!!!"
```

EDIT: Sorry I am using Windows 8 and Python 2.7.

I need help with a homework assignment. I can complete the assignment fine, but I would like know how to do it a different way.
So basically I have to write a knock knock joke in python. I want to do the "interrupting cow" joke but I don't know how to get the code to interrupt while typing. Here's what I have.

```
name = raw_input("Hi, what is your name?")
print "hi, " + name + ", nice to meet you."
a1 = raw_input("Would you like to hear a knock knock joke?").lower()
if a1 == "no":
    print "OK, thanks anyways"
elif a1 == "yes":
    raw_input ("Knock Knock")
    raw_input ("interrupting cow")
```

So I have it all the way up to where I would respond 'interrupting cow who' and it would interrupt with 'MOO!!!' in the middle of me typing. I've seen something about an end' ' code but it didn't really work, or maybe I didn't use it write. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: You would need to replace `raw_input ("interrupting cow")` with code to display "interrupting cow", then wait for them to start typing the response (something like http://code.activestate.com/recipes/134892/), then display "moo".

Comment: Which OS?  Unfortunately Python doesn't come with a portable `getch()` to get a single character at a time, which would really help here.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [***thread***](http://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html) (essentially a small task) for the interruption, starting the thread running in the background immediately before asking for input.

In the example below, I `def`ine a *function* "`punchline()`", which waits for 1 second before "mooing". This function is executed in the thread started by the call to [`start_new_thread()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html#thread.start_new_thread). See the linked documentation for more information.

```
import thread
import time


def punchline():
    time.sleep(1)
    print 'MOO'

# [...]

thread.start_new_thread(punchline, ())
raw_input("interrupting cow")
```

For best results, randomise the [`sleep`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep) time.

Comment: Excuse my lack of knowledge, but since this is my first program I would kind of like to understand it, would you mind explaining that code to me exactly? like what does 

thread.start_new_thread(punchline, ()) 
and
def punchline(): 
do?

Answer (score 1):

How about reading a random number (between 1 and len('interrupting cow who?')) of characters and then interrupting?

- [Python: read a single character from the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/python-read-a-single-character-from-the-user)
- [Python docs: random.randint](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randint)